# As of 2018, why did Putin get involved in Syria?

Tags: russian-federation, syria, geopolitics, western-world, vladimir-putin

When Russia first got involved in Syria, a few points came in my mind:

1. To distract the international community from Crimean annexation.
2. To secure a naval base in Syria so that they can get involve in Middle Eastern politics to challenge West's unmatched connection with oil rich countries.
3. To test newly developed weapons.

But, I am actually confused as the Syrian expedition costed him a lot of money and the outcome is not obvious. Are all of these points or any subset of them true?

As of 2018, why did Putin get involved in Syria?

**Note.** The linked question and answers do not fulfill my requirement. The question was asked in 2015, which falls short of later proceedings in Syria. Answers are all devoid of any substance, and do not add anything new to our knowledge base.

Comment: "The question was asked in 2015, which falls short of later proceedings in Syria." that's a good reason to update the answers to that question, or add a new answer. It's also possible to post a bounty on that question.

Answer (score 2):

Also have some point in my mind:

- stop destabilization of middle east - like in Iraq was. Support Assad and free Syria from western-backed(too many talks about new jeeps and stuff transferred from Europe and Israel) islamists
  There was a known Clark's list: https://www.globalresearch.ca/we-re-going-to-take-out-7-countries-in-5-years-iraq-syria-lebanon-libya-somalia-sudan-iran/5166 . So, ruining US plans is a reasonable aim, I think.

About your points - it is somehow incorrect to answering your question in your own question. But about them:

- Your first point. International (you mean western) community, especially its neocon and media parts are just unconversationable, so it cannot be the aim. It is silly to try to change their minds, like talking with a tree or stone. They respects force at most.

And also, about "distracting". Do you think that Crimean bridge is also a "distraction"? Do you think that China minds about US or EU opinion on its 'human rights' and so on? I guess not. So, I don't understand why Russia should mind about it.

This is a very great mistake to look at Russian actions as tries of gaining what west appretiates. Western world isn't a world goodness court where all countries should defend their positions.

- Your second point. I guess, you want to say improve influence in Syria - there are multiple bases. I think yes. Along with economic projects for Syrian rebuild after the war.
- Your third point. Of course. This is undisputable point, and this is very important

Comment: Downvoters, please, left comments above. Want to know your motivation.)

Comment: Globalresearch.ca is a fake news site peddling conspiracy theories, not a valid source.